# How to use user defined python function inside a sqlalchemy query filter?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a function in python is_valid_id(id) which returns True or False.
I want to use this function in my sqlalchmy query inside filter condition. My query is as below.

```py
result = session.query(tableName).filter(is_valid_id(id) == True).all()
```

This throwing the following error.

```
AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'strip'
```

Can you please tell how to use a user defined function inside sqlalchemy query.

I have tried using func keyword also. That is not working.

Comment: does this have anything to do with pandas?

Comment: No this is related to sqlalchemy .

Answer (score -1):

Right now you're saying filter by (True == True).all()
This doesn't do anything.

You need to say what you're filtering.

```
result = session.query(tableName).filter(tableName.columnName == condition).all()
```

It sounds to me like you should do something like this.
Grab everything, then loop through each object and see if your id returns true.
For example:

```
table_objects = session.query(tableName).all()
for current_object in table_objects:
    current_id = current_object.id
    is_current_id_valid = is_valid_id(current_id)
    if is_current_id_valid:
        print(f'this id is valid: {current_id}')
```

Comment: That's an antipattern that will result in a tablescan, unfortunately.